# Copy files task is not copying to Azure repos

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible

I have a inventory.txt in one folder of my azure repos. I need to copy that to another folder. I have used "Copy File task" but it copying file to the required folder only in agent machine.Its not reflecting in azure repos. What Can I do.

My Main Task is to give a packages_list variable in a inventory file. But this variable is being used by two yaml files which are two different folders and used for two different pipeline. For that  I have declared a packages_list variable in one of the folder and copy to another folder. ANy other alternativeees are much appreciated.

Comment: May I know what’s the status of this after the weekend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After copy the files to target folder, you need run git command to push changes to sync the changed folder back into Azure devops repo.

Please try with below steps to configure your pipeline:

[image]

(1) The first **Command line** task:

```
git config --global user.email "xxx@xx.com"
git config --global user.name "Merlin"

cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
git init
```

(2) In second task, execute the **`Copy file`** task.

(3) In next **Command line** task, do `git push` to push the changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m "File copied"
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/xxxx
git push -u origin HEAD:master
```

[image]

---

Since above command is modifying Azure repos, please enable **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** in agent job and ensure the corresponding [Build service account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=azure-devops#build-job-authorization-scope) has **Contribute** permission to Git repos. Just follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#enable-scripts-to-run-git-commands) to configure the permission setting.